# counting no of specific rows in a table using jquery(.each() function) also using .attr() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display the number of rows of a table using **.each()** function in jQuery and also using .attr() function. My code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="width: 290px; padding-left: 520px; padding-top: 155px;">
    <table id="mytable" border="1">
        <tr style="background-color: #DEB887" class="red"><td>1</td><td>Arun</td><td>B.Tech.</td><td>Sivakasi</td></tr>
        <tr style="background-color: ##F5F5DC" class="green"><td>2</td><td>Kumar</td><td>B.Com.</td><td>Madurai</td></tr>
        <tr style="background-color: #DEB887" class="red"><td>3</td><td>Rajesh</td><td>B.Sc.</td><td>Coimbatore</td></tr>
        <tr style="background-color: ##F5F5DC" class="green"><td>4</td><td>Gopinath</td><td>M.E.</td><td>Tirunelveli</td></tr>
        <tr style="background-color: #DEB887" class="red"><td>5</td><td>Deepak</td><td>M.Tech.</td><td>Chennai</td></tr>
        <tr style="background-color: ##F5F5DC" class="green"><td>6</td><td>Jerome</td><td>M.C.A.</td><td>Trichy</td></tr>
        <tr style="background-color: #DEB887" class="red"><td>7</td><td>Ashok</td><td>B.E.</td><td>Bangalore</td></tr>
        <tr style="background-color: ##F5F5DC" class="green"><td>8</td><td>Praveen</td><td>B.Tech.</td><td>Hyderabad</td></tr>
        <tr style="background-color: #DEB887" class="red"><td>9</td><td>Albert</td><td>B.B.A.</td><td>Tirupur</td></tr>
        <tr style="background-color: ##F5F5DC" class="green"><td>10</td><td>Jebastin</td><td>Ph.D.</td><td>Mumbai</td></tr>
        <tr style="background-color: ##F5F5DC" class="green"><td>11</td><td>Stephen</td><td>Ph.D.</td><td>Mumbai</td></tr>
    </table><br>
    <input type="button" value="Count for odd no colors" id="cnt" name="cnt" onclick="javascript:counting_values();">
</body>    
</html>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function counting_values()
    {
        $(function() {
          var red = 0 ,green = 0;
          $('#mytable tr').each( function() {
            if( $(this).attr('red',red) )
              red += 1;
            if( $(this).attr('green',green) )
              green += 1;
          });

          alert( 'Number of red rows:'+red );
          alert( 'Number of green rows:'+green );
        });
  }
</script>
```

I want to display the number of rows of **red & green classes** using .attr() function. But it does not gives me correct output.

If I click on the button, it should show **"Number of red rows : 5"** and **Number of green rows : 6"**. But now it shows that **"Number of red rows : 11"** and **Number of green rows : 11"**. This is the total records in the table.

Is my code correct or if there is any changes, please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your answer is acceptable one... Sorry for wrongly voted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set two counters (red and green) and check inside `each` whether they have the red or green classes:

```
var red = 0;
var green = 0;
$('#mytable tr').each(function(){
   if ($(this).hasClass('red')) {
       red++;
   }
   if ($(this).hasClass('green')) {
       green++;
   }
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zoy4L2b5/

Comment: probably it makes sense to simplify code? 
 
alert("Red " + $("#mytable tr.red").length);
alert("Green " + $("#mytable tr.green").length);

Comment: @Sergey B.: Yes, but that is explicitly *not* what the OP wanted. Check all the comments on the other answers. He wanted an `each`-based solution for some reason out of his control :)

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to iterate over the rows. you can get all object with class red/blue  along with `.length` to find their count:

```
function counting_values(){
  alert($('#mytable .red').length);
  //and 
  alert($('#mytable .green').length);
}
```

**Update:** iterating over table elements and alerting rows in it:

```
function counting_values(){

 var redrows=0;
 var greenrows=0;

 $('#mytable').find('tr.red,tr.green').each(function(){
  $(this).is('.red') ? redrows++ : greenrows++;
 });

 alert(redrows);
 alert(greenrows);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i need it using .each() function@Miliand Anantwar

Comment: @Arun_Indian: why do you want to complicate the solution??

Comment: My task is like that @Milind Anantwar

Comment: I did your given solution already. But they want to get them using .each() function. So only I searching for another solution.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar: You are *eaching* the `table`, not the rows in your last example...

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: thanks. was confused whether ops have multiple table.

Comment: `$(this).is('.red') ? redrows++ : greenrows++;` will also increase greenrows when there is no class (or a blue class, or whatever).

Comment: @LinkinTED: do you see any other rows out there?? they are not.

Comment: In this case there isn't, but I prefer to make the script so, that *if* there is another row added, the script still only counts the red and green rows. Or you could rename your counters to `redrows` and `otherrows`. It is at least worth mentioning in you post.

Comment: @LinkinTED: rather than that targetting only red and green rows would be more relevant

Comment: In the end it all depends on the users needs... :)

Answer (score 1):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2dmkrog8/)

```
$('#cnt').click(function () {
    alert($('#mytable .red').length);
});
```

Using class as selector will select all element with that class all you have to do is get the length of that  class

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2dmkrog8/1/)

```
$('#cnt').click(function () {
    //alert($('#mytable .red').length);
    var count = 0;
    $('#mytable .red').each(function(){
            count++
        });
    alert(count);
});
```

But i dont think this is a good idea the more simple the code the better

Comment: But is it not possible using .each() function?

Comment: @Arun_Indian it is possible depending on the need

Comment: But how is it possible @Pekka

Comment: I know this is complicated, but the client's request is this. So only i need this. Anyway, thank you for your help

Comment: @Arun_Indian did you try the updated fiddle i made it the way you wanted it

Comment: @Arun_Indian what do you want to do maybe i can be of any help if you explain a bit more

Comment: @Arun_Indian there is if you click on the button it will alert 5 because there are 5 with class red

Comment: No its still not alert.

Comment: did you get alert?because i am getting alert no error found what browser are you using did you click on the button?

Comment: I use Mozilla Firefox v38.0 and my OS is Linux mint

Comment: i am sure something is wrong with the browser maybe you stopped the alert from popping up.close the browser and open again and give it a try

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2dmkrog8/2/ try this one i made a console.log so you can check it the console instead

Comment: glad i can help happy coding

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, the easiest way is to use `$('#mytable .red').length`.

But sure, you can complicate your code by iterating your table:

```
$(function() {
  var red = 0 ,
      green = 0;
  $('#mytable tr').each( function() {
    if( $(this).hasClass('red') )
      red++;
    if( $(this).hasClass('green') )
      green++;
  });

  alert( 'Number of red rows:'+red );
  alert( 'Number of green rows:'+green );
});
```